# Toggle function not working properly

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a simple toggle function to show and hide content. It is triggered on the click of the H2, and added a "show all" / "hide all" function.

The issue I'm having is that when you expand a couple of the content areas, then click "Show All" it hides the open ones and shows the hidden ones instead of just showing the hidden ones. I know that its caused by the ".toggle" function firing and toggling the open ones closed. In theory I suspect I'll have to add a class to the expanded ones and run a check to see if any are open and don't toggle those, only expanding the hidden ones. To close with the "Close all" button I'd have to do the inverse?

How do I remedy this? [example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/LBBbr/)

Comment: @Nanne and ShankarSangoli awesome! thx for straightening me out on that. wish i could mark both as the correct answer, just went with who answered first. Thanks guys, really appreciate it. Esp the demo in Shankar's, awesome man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `toggle` will just toggle the state(show/hide) of the element. In this case don't use `slideToggle`, instead use `slideUp/slideDown` conditionally. Try this.

```
$(".toggleAll").click(function() {
    if($(this).text() == 'Show All'){
        $(".faq p").slideDown("slow");
        $(this).text('Hide All');
        $(".faq h2").addClass('active');
    }
    else{
        $(".faq p").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).text('Show All');
        $(".faq h2").removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LBBbr/2/)**

Comment: greatly appreciated the demo and the knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Simple: Don't use "`toggle()`" for the show-all button, but use "`show()`". ditto for the hide-all, use "`hide()"`.

Only use `toggle()` for the single clicks